# run a script at shutdown in Debian

Tags: debian, networking, shell-script, shutdown

I am using Debian wheezy. My problem is, I am using a limited 2.5 GB net connection and would like to capture my usage before shutting down. My idea is simply running a script as:

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> ~/mydatausage.txt
ifconfig -a >> ~/mydatausage.txt
```

at the time of shutdown.

How can I run this script at shutdown, as root?

Answer (score 2):

Put the script in `/etc/rc0.d/` directory, make sure it has execute permissions, and follow the naming convention `S*`

In your case, you can save your above script in a file at `/etc/rc0.d/S00myscript` & make sure it is executable by running `chmod +x /etc/rc0.d/S00myscript`

Comment: can you improve the answer by direct instructions.

Comment: Done. You can try the instructions now.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following instruction

```
/etc/init.d/REDME
/etc/rc?.d/REDME
```

you need to put  the script in /etc/init.d/ and make a symbolic link in /etc/rc0.d/ this corresponds to the shutdown runlevel and if you want to execute the script when rebooting then make a symbolic link in rc6.d. If you list the folder rc0.d then you will see the script starts with S or K. S come from Start if you want to run script and K come from Kill if you want to stop script

Comment: thanks for your answer ,can you improve the answer by direct instructions.

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work anymore (I'm using Debian 8.7)